# facebook API for PHP POST issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having trouble with the new Facebook API. I have a simple test page that looks like this, which is basically copied directly from the documentation examples:

```
<?php

// require PHP SDK
require 'facebook.php';

// Create our application instance
// (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'MY_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'MY_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    var_dump($user_profile); // works properly, as long as the $return below is commented out

    /* 
    WORKS FINE UP TO HERE.
    IF I ATTEMPT TO DO THE POST BELOW, I GET
    OAuthException: An unknown error has occurred.
    AND I AM NOT SHOWN AS LOGGED IN.
    */

    $fbpost = array(
        'message' => 'test message',
        'name' => 'name',
        'caption' => 'caption',
        'link' => 'http://localhost',
        'picture' => 'http://www.lov2xlr8.no/usa/bilder/63impala2.jpg'
    );

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'POST', $fbpost);

            /* END OF PROBLEM SECTION */

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'manage_pages, offline_access, publish_stream, read_stream'));
}

?>
```

The test page works fine. But when I attempt to combine it with a POST test as shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/), it fails with an unknown OAuth error and won't post to my timeline.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

[EDIT]

Adding dump of `FacebookApiException` (minus the stack trace):

```
object(FacebookApiException)[2]
  protected 'result' => 
    array (size=1)
      'error' => 
        array (size=3)
          'message' => string 'An unknown error has occurred.' (length=30)
          'type' => string 'OAuthException' (length=14)
          'code' => int 1
  protected 'message' => string 'An unknown error has occurred.' (length=30)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 0
  protected 'file' => string 'base_facebook.php' (length=79)
  protected 'line' => int 1340
```

[EDIT 2]

It appears that it's having the problem with the `link` element of the post object. When I comment out the `link` it works as expected and successfully posts. It turns out that apparently Facebook won't accept `localhost` as the link attribute. If I change it to `http://google.com` or some other accessible URL, it works properly.

Comment: Whats the complete output of the `FacebookApiException` exception?

Comment: Added exception info above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it's having the problem with the link element of the post object. When I comment out the link it works as expected and successfully posts. It turns out that apparently Facebook won't accept localhost as the link attribute. If I change it to http://google.com or some other accessible URL, it works properly.

Comment: Of course they don’t accept that, because the whole point of sharing links is that Facebook’s scraper can visit that URL to extract meta data from it, and that other users seeing that posted link can visit it – and they can’t do that with a page that is available only on your own computer.

Comment: I realize that. . .now.